# top command shows inaccurate TIME+

Tags: linux

My machine is just up for around 10 minutes. However top command shows the following inaccurate TIME

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5721 root      20   0 15424 1588  840 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.02 top
    1 root      20   0 19360 1532 1224 S  0.0  0.0  4727184h init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  4723057h kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 ksoftirqd/1
   10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/1
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/2
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/2
   15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/3
   18 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 300194:20 watchdog/3
   19 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/4
   20 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/4
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/4
```

```
# ps p 1 u
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1 205788576  0.0 19360 1532 ?     Ss   13:22 68882688:50 /sbin/init
# uptime
 13:35:17 up 8 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
#
```

Can anyone tell what caused this huge TIME+ number?
Here is /proc/1/stat

```
# cat /proc/1/stat
1 (init) S 0 1 1 0 -1 4202752 2693 1076732 9 366 35687438872 1666098882994 1074795224736 1071709728674 20 0 1 0 3 19824640 383 18446744073709551615 139708515631104 139708515771252 140737139200704 140737139199784 139708497335507 0 0 4096 536962595 18446744071580512361 0 0 0 12 0 0 11 0 0
#
```

Thank you,
eii

Answer (score 2):

TIME+ is the cumulative time displayed. It is the total CPU time the task has used since it is started. To find actual running of process you can use **ps** command.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell what caused this huge TIME+ number? Here is /proc/1/stat

TIME is displayed in `minutes:seconds.hundredths`